# Some troubles with fonts for embedded system

Tags: qt, ubuntu, fonts, embedded-linux

When I run my application on Set Top Box the font quality degrades. The degradation manifests itself as follows:
1. The letters in a word is not the same brightness, the pixels of one letter also differ in brightness;
2. Vertical Alignment moves down, in the worst case the bottom line bump on the top.
3. There is a feeling that used font is not I wanted (although the log indicates that the font that's what I need).

Most interestingly, it's fine in the desktop version of the same code, the same fonts.
Below are additional information about used enviroment and experiments that I done.

1. Fonts - **TrueType**, is loaded into the system using **QFontDatabase :: addApplicationFont**;

   **For PC:    QT 5.2.1**

   **For STB:   QT 4.7.2**

   I use for fonts **QFont :: PreferAntialias, setStretch (100)**
2. I have replaced setPixelSize calls on setPointSize - did not help;
3. Suspecting QT version - made application for PC  using qt 4.8 - for this version all are well;
4. I have played with different weights and sizes of font - used for this font information, which pulled via QFontDatabase. Did not help;
5. I have tested on different plasmas with different diagonal - one result.

The last thing I have learned - DPI. Here are DPI for my PC and STB:

```
            Physical          Logical
      STB    72x72             72x72

      PC    90x116             96x96
```

Well, perhaps all. If you help I will be very grateful.

Comment: Heh, you answered it yourself. You're using two Qt versions so drastically different that it's totally expected they'll behave differently. Not to mention that Qt 4.6.0 has been unsupported since, like, 5 years?

Comment: Unfortunately I should use Qt 4.6.0  for embedded system